# React js not able to start Development Server

Tags: reactjs

When I am trying to npm start getting this error can anyone please help me to solve this erro.
$ npm start

> hrmanagement@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start

Starting the development server...

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/esm/index.js 67:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (67:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   return getFeed(parseDOM(feed, options));
| }

> export * as DomUtils from "domutils"; // Old name for DomHandler
> |
> | export { DomHandler as DefaultHandler };